# impllement bootstrap checkbox in drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming

I need to add the checkbox-inline class (as mentioned in bootstrap checkbox tutorial) to show checkboxes inline one after another instead of one checkbox per line.

How can I add the class to a checkbox being an form (content type) element?

Comment: The question as written is about plain CSS styles (_How do I make checkboxes appear inlined?_) If you are trying to change a Drupal form, you need to add more details, including what you tried, and why it didn't work. Also, since you are referring a tutorial, it would help if you linked it.

Comment: isn't this question about adding a class to a checkbox ?? you could do that here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_checkboxes/8